# How do you set up a login component that is not in the TabBarIOS?

Tags: react-native

I want all my views to be in a TabBarIOS except one - the login view. Currently in my app.js I render the TabBarIOS with items each containing a NavigatorIOS that loads my different components. But how do I organize my project to have a separate component that doesn't show the tab bar at all?

Comment: Can't you just have a top level navigator that incorporates your existing tabbar? Then that could navigate between the tabbed view and the non tabbed view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you use a modal instead?

https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-modal